# Milestones Roadmap construction using tikz and clickable links

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{default}
\newdimen\ipefs
\newcounter{ipePage}\newcounter{ipeView}
\newcounter{ipePages}\newcounter{ipeViews}
\newcommand{\PageTitle}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\ipesymbol}[4]{$\bullet$}
\def\ipedefinecolors#1{\ipecolorpreamble{#1}\let\ipecolorpreamble\relax}
\def\ipecolorpreamble#1{\usepackage[#1]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{red}{rgb}{1,0,0}
    \definecolor{blue}{rgb}{0,0,1}
    \definecolor{green}{rgb}{0,1,0}
    \definecolor{yellow}{rgb}{1,1,0}
    \definecolor{orange}{rgb}{1,0.647,0}
    \definecolor{gold}{rgb}{1,0.843,0}
    \definecolor{purple}{rgb}{0.627,0.125,0.941}
    \definecolor{gray}{gray}{0.745}
    \definecolor{brown}{rgb}{0.647,0.165,0.165}
    \definecolor{navy}{rgb}{0,0,0.502}
    \definecolor{pink}{rgb}{1,0.753,0.796}
    \definecolor{seagreen}{rgb}{0.18,0.545,0.341}
    \definecolor{turquoise}{rgb}{0.251,0.878,0.816}
    \definecolor{violet}{rgb}{0.933,0.51,0.933}
    \definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.545}
    \definecolor{darkcyan}{rgb}{0,0.545,0.545}
    \definecolor{darkgray}{gray}{0.663}
    \definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.392,0}
    \definecolor{darkmagenta}{rgb}{0.545,0,0.545}
    \definecolor{darkorange}{rgb}{1,0.549,0}
    \definecolor{darkred}{rgb}{0.545,0,0}
    \definecolor{lightblue}{rgb}{0.678,0.847,0.902}
    \definecolor{lightcyan}{rgb}{0.878,1,1}
    \definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.827}
    \definecolor{lightgreen}{rgb}{0.565,0.933,0.565}
    \definecolor{lightyellow}{rgb}{1,1,0.878}
    \definecolor{black}{gray}{0}
    \definecolor{white}{gray}{1}
}
\makeatletter
\def\ipesetcolor#1#2#3{\def\current@color{#1 #2 #3 rg #1 #2 #3 RG}\pdfcolorstack\@pdfcolorstack push{\current@color}}
\def\iperesetcolor{\pdfcolorstack\@pdfcolorstack pop}
\makeatother



% The following is auto-generated by the TikZ exporter.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{ipe} % ipe compatibility library




\ipedefinecolors{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcount\bigpoint\dimen0=0.01bp\bigpoint=\dimen0
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    %   \frametitle{Pic}
            \begin{picture}(100,300)
            \setbox0=\hbox{\normalsize
                \ipesetcolor{0}{0}{0}%
                \begin{tikzpicture}[ipe import, baseline, trim left]
                    \filldraw[black]
                    (160, 320)
                    .. controls (128, 288) and (128, 280) .. (165.3333, 273.3333)
                    .. controls (202.6667, 266.6667) and (277.3333, 261.3333) .. (320, 253.3333)
                    .. controls (362.6667, 245.3333) and (373.3333, 234.6667) .. (365.3333, 218.6667)
                    .. controls (357.3333, 202.6667) and (330.6667, 181.3333) .. (317.3333, 168)
                    .. controls (304, 154.6667) and (304, 149.3333) .. (352, 144)
                    .. controls (400, 138.6667) and (496, 133.3333) .. (546.6667, 130.6667)
                    .. controls (597.3333, 128) and (602.6667, 128) .. (610.6667, 128)
                    .. controls (618.6667, 128) and (629.3333, 128) .. (634.6667, 128)
                    .. controls (640, 128) and (640, 128) .. (640, 120)
                    .. controls (640, 112) and (640, 96) .. (640, 88)
                    .. controls (640, 80) and (640, 80) .. (584, 80)
                    .. controls (528, 80) and (416, 80) .. (349.3333, 90.6667)
                    .. controls (282.6667, 101.3333) and (261.3333, 122.6667) .. (253.3333, 138.6667)
                    .. controls (245.3333, 154.6667) and (250.6667, 165.3333) .. (261.3333, 176)
                    .. controls (272, 186.6667) and (288, 197.3333) .. (293.3333, 205.3333)
                    .. controls (298.6667, 213.3333) and (293.3333, 218.6667) .. (258.6667, 224)
                    .. controls (224, 229.3333) and (160, 234.6667) .. (128, 245.3333)
                    .. controls (96, 256) and (96, 272) .. (144, 320);
                    \filldraw[draw=white, dashed, fill=black]
                    (128, 80)
                    -- (128, 80);
                    \draw[ ->]
                    (0, 240)
                    .. controls (0, 240) and (0, 240) .. (0, 240);
                    \draw[ dashed, ->]
                    (464, 0)
                    .. controls (464, 0) and (464, 0) .. (464, 0);
                    \draw[white, dashed, ->]
                    (151.3815, 321.3463)
                    .. controls (140.9296, 308.7319) and (136.7849, 303.8664) .. (133.4511, 299.5115)
                    .. controls (130.1173, 295.1565) and (127.5945, 291.3122) .. (126.1528, 287.7682)
                    .. controls (124.7112, 284.2241) and (124.3508, 280.9804) .. (124.3508, 277.4965)
                    .. controls (124.3508, 274.0125) and (124.7112, 270.2883) .. (127.3542, 267.4651)
                    .. controls (129.9972, 264.6419) and (134.9228, 262.7197) .. (162.4941, 257.8542)
                    .. controls (190.0654, 252.9887) and (240.2824, 245.1798) .. (269.9561, 240.2542)
                    .. controls (299.6298, 235.3286) and (308.7601, 233.2863) .. (315.9683, 231.4242)
                    .. controls (323.1765, 229.5621) and (328.4625, 227.8802) .. (331.0454, 225.057)
                    .. controls (333.6284, 222.2338) and (333.5082, 218.2693) .. (328.6427, 211.902)
                    .. controls (323.7772, 205.5348) and (314.1663, 196.7648) .. (306.0571, 188.2352)
                    .. controls (297.9479, 179.7055) and (291.3404, 171.4161) .. (287.2557, 165.169)
                    .. controls (283.1711, 158.9219) and (281.6093, 154.7171) .. (281.6694, 150.8727)
                    .. controls (281.7294, 147.0284) and (283.4114, 143.5444) .. (287.6762, 139.64)
                    .. controls (291.941, 135.7356) and (298.7888, 131.4106) .. (309.2407, 127.8666)
                    .. controls (319.6925, 124.3226) and (333.7485, 121.5595) .. (350.5676, 118.6762)
                    .. controls (367.3867, 115.7929) and (386.9689, 112.7895) .. (412.1375, 110.6271)
                    .. controls (437.3061, 108.4646) and (468.061, 107.1431) .. (499.8971, 106.3622)
                    .. controls (531.7333, 105.5813) and (564.6506, 105.3411) .. (595.4356, 105.311)
                    .. controls (626.2205, 105.281) and (654.873, 105.4612) .. (654.873, 105.4612);
                    \filldraw[fill=darkcyan]
                    (469.7547, 61.608) circle[radius=6.6152];
                    \fill[red]
                    (469.7547, 61.411) circle[radius=2.4723];
                    \filldraw[fill=darkcyan]
                    (393.6759, 158.5021) circle[radius=6.6152];
                    \fill[red]
                    (393.6759, 158.3051) circle[radius=2.4723];
                    \filldraw[fill=darkcyan]
                    (239.2, 119.035) circle[radius=6.6152];
                    \fill[red]
                    (239.2, 118.838) circle[radius=2.4723];
                    \filldraw[fill=darkcyan]
                    (126.498, 218.0607) circle[radius=6.6152];
                    \fill[red]
                    (126.498, 217.8637) circle[radius=2.4723];
                    \node[ipe node, font=\Large]
                    at (432, 32) {\thesection \quad Introduction};
                    \node[ipe node, font=\Large]
                    at (352, 176) { \hyperlink{thesentence}{Literature Review}};
                    \node[ipe node, font=\Large]
                    at (96, 192) {References};
                    \node[ipe node, font=\Large]
                    at (192, 96) {Objectives};
                    \node[ipe node, font=\Large]
                    at (352, 256) {Work};
                    \filldraw[fill=darkcyan]
                    (374.498, 244.0607) circle[radius=6.6152];
                    \fill[red]
                    (374.498, 243.8637) circle[radius=2.4723];
                \end{tikzpicture}
                %
                \iperesetcolor}
            \count0=\dp0\divide\count0 by \bigpoint
            \pdfxform attr{/IpeId 1 /IpeStretch 1 /IpeDepth \the\count0}0\put(-110,40){\pdfrefxform\pdflastxform}
        \end{picture}
    \end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
\end{frame}
\section{Literature Review}
\begin{frame}
    \hypertarget{thesentence}{Literature Review}
    \frametitle{Literature Review}
\end{frame}
\section{Objectives}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Objectives}
\end{frame}
\section{Work}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Work}
\end{frame}
\section{References}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{References}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: intended]

Comment: Please read this comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685508/draw-with-tikz-such-that-clicking-on-those-will-take-you-to-the-corresponding-se#comment1700817_685508 This site is not a draw-this-for-me site. You should show what you already tried and at which point your are stuck.

Comment: Welcome. // Yes, we can. And you can too, once understood the Minimal Introduction and the tutorials in the big manual ...

Comment: Though it's closed, not clear to me what the newly postedd code intends to show. Perhaps it's a solution?

Comment: The `ipe` library loaded via `\usetikzlibrary{ipe}` is not available to us, so we cannot compile this code. Maybe provide a link where one can find the code? Maybe its this: https://github.com/QBobWatson/ipe2tikz ?

Comment: Please also explain in more detail what your question is currently. For me, even when loading the `ipe` library from the above link, the code does not compile and throws an error. Is this maybe the problem you would like to solve?

Answer (score 1):

*(Your code does not compile and includes custom libraries which I don't have, so I to strip the example down a "tiny" bit ...)*

You can make TikZ nodes act as links to your sections like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}}

\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\hyperlink{sec:#1}{#1\quad\nameref{sec:#1}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.01]
      \node[font=\Large] at (432, 32) {\foo{1}};
      \node[font=\Large] at (352, 176) {\foo{2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Introduction}
\end{frame}

\section{Literature Review}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Literature Review}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]